# Add % label to columns charts on Power BI

Tags: plot, powerbi, label

I have a table with the historical data of tickets with the creation date and a column that said if the resolution time was accomplish or not.

I create a column plot to resume the amount of tiquets by month and accomplish or not. But I need to add label that say % of tiquets according to the accomplish of month (for example the 85% accomplish on june and 15% dont. I dont know how to add the % label

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, but you may just need to set the formatting by clicking on the field and then clicking on the % sign in the column tools.

[image]